# Swift3: How can I add a String type value to an UI Label in which a calculated value has already been pasted?

Tags: swift, switch-statement, xcode6

When doing so I get the Error Code:

> Cannot assign value of type '(String, String)' to type 'String?'

As you can see below, I have already converted the Numbers to String values which didn't help.

Ultimately I want to have an UI Label which displays a value + String depending on a switch function.

The Value is going to switch Units and the UI Label should say ( 256 Days or 3.5 hours and for the last example not 0.14 days)

Assigning the Units when printing inti the XCode Console is easy. What I would need is to copy the Console Output ( Target Output) and then paste it into a UI Label, if the other method doesnt work.

Here the Code :

switch Differenz {

```
    case 1...9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999   : print  (Differenzstring,"Years")


    case 0.0027...0.99 :  print ( Differenz*365, "Days ")


    case 0.000114...0.00269 : print (Differenz * 365*24,"Hours")


    case 0.0000019...0.0001139 : print (Differenz * 365 * 24 * 60, "Minutes" )


    case 0.000000000001 ... 0.00000189 : print (Differenz * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60,"Seconds")


    case 0...0:  print    ( "Time (almost) stops")





    default : print  ( "Calculation failed" )



    }


    // Units not inegrated yet, Result will therefore be in Years perfect would be the Cosnole Output, provided by the Switch Statement also being pasted into "Output Label"


    Output.text = String ( Differenz )


}
```

Comment: share your code here with question

Comment: **As you can see I have already converted the Numbers to String values** Where I need to see for that ?

Comment: converted the Numbers to String Where is the main issue then ? And need to edit the Question As you had not by mistaken provided the code to see '

Comment: Thanks Guys , I am new to StackOverflow so Sorry for the Inconvenience caused. Hope this edit makes it better. @Prashant Tukadiya, @ iOS Geek,

Answer (score 0):

could you try this out?

```
var usedTimeLabel = "seconds" //reassign this value when doing switch
Output.text = "\(Differenz) \(usedTimeLabel)"
```